# Regular Expression to parse html

Tags: php, regex

please see code :

```
$result = "<b>Associated Names</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;[<a href='http://www.examples.com/authors.html?act=change&id=6141&item=associated'><u>Edit</u></a>]</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td class='text' align='left'>G&#12539;R<br />G-R<br />         </td>"

preg_match_all("/<b>Associated Names.{10,100}<td class='text' align='left'>((.*<br \/>)*).*<\/td>/sU", $result, $assoc);
var_dump($assoc);
-----------------------------------------------------------
RESULT 
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '<b>Associated Names</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class='text' align='left'>G&#12539;R<br />G-R<br />         </td>' (length=135)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string '' (length=0)
```

I want it return

```
array(
    1 => 
     array
      0 => string 'G&#12539;R',
    2 => 
     array
      0 => string> 'G-R'
)
```

it is a matter of parentheses ((.*)*) i want fix it, please help me

Comment: What are you matching your regex against?

Comment: It is best not to use regular expressions to parse HTML. Try an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Can we have message on the "Ask Question" page telling users not to try to parse HTML with regexs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't try to parse HTML with regular expressions, it [invokes the wrath of Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Try using [the DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [xpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to target the specific elements and attributes you are attempting to extract.

(I'd provide an xpath example, but it's still on my to-learn list... :) )

Comment: Unfortunately, some times it is the only way, because not every page is well formated. Many a times, Zend Dom Query has failed to create the dom correctly and I 've got wrong results. Not a fault of the framework of course, but parsing can get messy. I use both approaches, ad hoc.

Comment: @john, have you tried to run the page through [tidy](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) first?

Comment: yes, for a specific page that was quite troublesome (scraping project), i used an external tidy service before creating the dom, without success. For the same page, I also tried using a ready made class to tidy it. It always gave back half the page. I decided not to dig deeper. :)